# AWS api gateway - multiple graphql microservices endpoint api routing

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, graphql, microservices, gateway

I have the below graphql microservices 

`- /graphql1 - with userList as the query - fetches the user records from nosql db
- /graphql2 - with accountList as the query - fetches the account records from sql db
- /graphql3 - with transactionList as the query - fetches the transactions records from static file`

All these 3 microservice run on their own docker container.

i would like to host these 3 microservices through one single aws api gateway
i.e. `/api`
when the 

`query is userlist - api should redirect the request to /graphql1
query is accountList - api should redirect the request to /graphql2
query is transactionList - api should redirect the request to /graphql3`

AWS API gateway can point to different endpoint based on method or contexturl, in this case , all graphql requests would be post to /api , with query as the body. Hence the challenge. Any help or guidance is really appreciated.